# how to decode a string in a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have code in javascript:

```
var location = '&quot;HCM - NYC (New York, NY)&quot;';
td_Details.innerText = location;
```

Now I want to decode the text location to

"HCM - NYC (New York, NY)"

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to call your variable `location`, that's a reserved word. It didn't worked too well for me.

Comment: @Kobi it's not a reserved word, it's just a global variable that browsers attach to the `window` object.

Comment: @Kobi `location` is not a reserved word. It is a client side object, so using it may be inadvisable but has no negative effects (unless you want to use the object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific function in JavaScript which will decode HTML entities, however you can assign an `innerHTML` property to an element and then read it back.

```
x = document.createElement('div');
x.innerHTML = "&quot;test&quot;";
console.log(x.innerHTML); // => "test"
```

This will work for any HTML entities, not just &quot;

**edit**:

As pointed out below, you're half-way there, you're just using the wrong property.

Change:

```
td_Details.innerText = location;
```

to:

```
td_Details.innerHTML = location;
```

For future reference, `innerHTML` is available in all browsers. `innerText` is not.

Comment: +1 - He already *has* an HTML element, `td_Details`. He's just using the wrong property.

Comment: @Tomalak - nice catch I didn't even notice.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the &quot; just use the following:

```
location = location.replace(/&quot;/g, '');
```

You may have actually meant to include the quotes in your output. To do so, do this instead:

```
location = location.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
```

Comment: Your code removes it, but I think you want to replace it with a quote - `replace(/&quot;/g, '"')`

Comment: Ah, yes, I had misinterpreted the quotes as not being included in the desired output. I'll update my answer; thanks!