# How to get element's content without converting &quot to "?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, escaping

I'm parsing JSON that is contained in an HTML element.

Consider this markup:

```
<div id="1">
    {"string":["&quot;\u041a\u0410\u041a&quot;"]}
</div>
```

And this script:

```
var a = $.parseJSON($("#1").html())
```

​
This will return an error ("Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token \"), because the `&quot`s are converted to `"`s by the `html()` method.

How can I make jQuery not parse HTML in this case? `$.text()` doesn't work either. Or am I doing something terribly wrong?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VJvpY/6/

**EDIT:** Note that the error will be displayed in the console only.

**EDIT2:** I need the JSON to be parsed and to create a JS object with it.

Comment: I don't think you can, jQuery isn't the one doing the parsing. Take a look at the content the browser gives you. One way around this is to place the json in a textarea and get the textarea's value.

Comment: So jQuery has no access to the actual markup, including the `&quot`s?

Comment: Correct, by the time jQuery can access it, the browser has already parsed it.

Comment: Please see my comment to Kevin B's answer.

Comment: @exizt hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757203/how-to-decode-a-string-in-a-varible-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up escaping all the `&`s in the JSON server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can't without placing the json in a textarea so that the browser doesn't parse it (jQuery isn't the one messing up your quotes.)

However, your json still can't be parsed by jquery due to the "/", i'm not sure how to fix that. Even after escaping them it still doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/VJvpY/3/

Comment: [You can stringify the JSON & then parse it, it will work as expected.](http://jsfiddle.net/VJvpY/4/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy However that goes back to parsing the quotes! Which is why i believe jquery is choking on it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy This way the JSON doesn't actually get parsed - it stays a string. I need an object to be created with the JSON string.

Comment: @exizt I think you are going to have to just resort to not returning characters such as `\u041a` with your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is show the JSON as text? You can just wrap it in a pre

http://jsfiddle.net/VJvpY/5/

Comment: I'm actually trying to pass an object from PHP to JS this way.